# Does it make sense to process List<InputVariables> in InvocableMethod?

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

As I see InvocableMethod always receives List.
Now in my method I handle it like this:

```
List<ReturnVariables> returnList
for (InputVariables input : InputVariablesList) {
  ...
  returnList.add(...);
}
return returnList;
```

Does that make sense? Are there cases when we get several InputVariables?
Or can I always refer to input like inputVariablesList.get(0)?

Comment: Check out the [flow bulkification docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5). You should never use `[0]` - the fact that Salesforce provides such examples is terrible. You should at least iterate them. Ideally you would then do all processing once, then split out the results as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is being called from Flow, then yes, the call to the invocable is typically [bulkified](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5) by the flow:

> Elements that create, update, or delete records When a record is
> created, updated, or deleted, the transaction performs a DML
> statement.

- Create Records elements
- Update Records elements
- Delete Records elements
- Quick Action,
- Post to Chatter, or Submit for Approval core actions
- **Apex Action elements—depending on the specific Apex action**

So if you have a record triggered flow that invokes the Invocable, and there are 50 records in the transaction, InputVariablesList will have 50 items that you need to handle, because the invocable is only called once by the flow engine

Here is a contrived example to demonstrate the concept:
I have a simple invocable, which is called from a subflow. Notice the debug statement so we can see how many times it is called:

```
public with sharing class RT_Invocable_POC {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static FlowOutput[] getSomeData(List<FlowInput> params) {
        FlowOutput[] results = new List<FlowOutput>();
        Integer i = 0;

        for (FlowInput param : params) {
            System.debug(param);
            i ++;
            FlowOutput flowOutputTemp = new FlowOutput();
            try {
                Id soId = (Id) param.sInput;
                flowOutputTemp.sResponse = soId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
                Task t = new Task ();
                t.Subject = soId + flowOutputTemp.sResponse;
                t.ActivityDate = system.today();
                t.Status = 'Not Started';
                t.WhatId = soId;
                flowOutputTemp.tTask = t;
                System.debug(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                flowOutputTemp.sError = e.getMessage();
            }
            results.add(flowOutputTemp);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public class FlowInput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String sInput;

    }

    public class FlowOutput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String sError;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String sResponse;
        @InvocableVariable
        public Task tTask;
    }

}
```

The Sub flow is called from a Record Triggered Flow on Account. For each account in the trigger, the RT Flow calls the sub flow, which passes in the Account Id from the record variable into the sub flow, which then calls the invocable, gets back a task and creates it.

But note - unlike in Apex, I have not had to bulkify anything. But if you create three accounts in one transaction, and look in the debug logs, you will only see 2 DML statements, but all 6 DML rows. And when you look for the system debug in the invocable, you will see it is called once, and iterates three times - one for each account.

[image: Sub Flow calls invocable]
[image: Record Trigger Flow]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I read the article, but I'm not 100% sure I got it right. If I have a Flow, inside of which in Loop I call 50 times Another Flow, which calls Invocable Method. Am I correct, Invocable Method will only be called 1 time where List<InputVariables>.size() == 50?

Comment: If you calling an invocable in a loop, you would need to test that - generally, it is best to avoid any action in a loop unless absolutely necessary.
But it is easy enough to test - add a debug statement to the invocable, and you'll see how many times it is invoked in the logs

Comment: @MaxVitko In your example, the class would be called 50 times. The correct way to bulkify would be to pass in a collection of variables to the subflow, so it can then call the invocable method just once.

Comment: @sfdxfox So... As i understand, if i create a new subflow, that get a collection and invoke my apex method in loop, then my method will invoked only 1 time?

Comment: Still don't understand how to get multiple values in List<InputVariables>. 
If I get a collection of values in Subflow, I still need to call Invocable Method in Loop to send it the values from the collection (It calls Invocable Method every time). 
Maybe I can find an example somewhere?

Comment: How does the flow get initiated? Record triggered, or Screen\Autolaunched?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Do you mean the Flow that calls the invocable method? It's Autolaunched.
Basically I have a Record Triggered Flow, inside of which I need to call Subflow for each Related record. Inside of this Subflow i call Invocable method.

Comment: Ok - edited answer with example of how a record triggered flow can call a sub flow => invocable, and flow will bulkify it